# VB6 - Call Function from Byte Array

Tags: c#, vb6, byte, .net-assembly

In C#, you could call,

```
Assembly.Load(byte[]).GetType("Class").GetMethod("method").Invoke(null, new object[] {
                    "I'm a parameter"
            });
```

Is there a VB6 equivalent?

Comment: `Assembly.Load(byte[])` is incorrect.

Comment: Do you really want a VB6 equivalent, or a VB.Net equivalent? If it is VB6, do you want to call a COM DLL or a .Net DLL?

Comment: A VB6 equivalent. I would be loading an ActiveX DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no equivalence. Since .COM don't have that feature. But if you want to call with string(Also with nearest[I say it different because it is'nt from byte array), you can use

`CallByName(object as Object, funcName as String, functype as vbCallType, paramArray args as any)`

object is object that you want to invoke. It can be a result of CreateObject() function, funcName is a string describing a name, functype is a type of function. It can be a sub, function get or set. The arg is a arg you want to pass. The two last argument might wrong. So please check out at object ecplorer. The arg might paramArray or an array. The enum name of functype might CallType or other.

Answer (score -1):

```
Assembly.Load(parameter).[GetType]("Class").GetMethod("method").Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {"I'm a parameter"})
```